# Run Powershell Script as Administrator remotely

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, access-denied, invoke-command

Script_A.ps1 on Server A:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName Server B -ScriptBlock{
     Set-Location "C:\Path"
     .\Script_B.ps1
}
```

The Script "Script_B.ps1":

```
Set-Location "C:\Path"
.\Script_C.ps1 -Verb RunAs -Force
```

Script_C needs elevated permissions to execute. I can edit Script_A and Script_B but NOT Script_C.

My Problem is if I execute Script_A there is the error on Script_C:

```
Access Denied
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Script_C.ps1
    + PSComputerName        : Server_B
```

Note: Script_C can execute, but it checks if it got started in the elevated mode and if it did not it gives me the access denied error. What am I missing that would it make work?

Comment: Remote scripts run as admin anyway without runas.

Comment: It is also without the -verb runas not working

Comment: You need to start PS by right clicking and select Run As Admin.  To run script on remote machine As Admin you replace the colon in the file name with a dollar sign.

Comment: @jdweng, unless you're targeting the very same machine with remoting (which only makes sense for testing), you do _not_ need to elevate a session _locally_ in order to run remote commands with elevation.
Re " replace the colon in the file name with a dollar sign": UNC paths to administrative shares (e.g. ``\\server1\C$``) are _not_ needed when running in a remote session - such sessions see their local file system as usual.

Answer (score 1):

- The **only way to get a remote PowerShell session to execute *elevated*** (with admin privileges) is to **connect with a user account** (either implicitly or via `-Credential`) that **has administrative privileges (also) on the target machine**.
- With such an account, the session *automatically and invariably* runs elevated.

  - Conversely, you can *not* request elevation from *inside a remote session* - there is no way to present a [UAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control) dialog.

---

In other words, you need to ensure the following:

- With respect to your [`Invoke-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command) call:

  - *either*: make the call from a user account that has administrative privileges (also) on the target computer(s)
  - *or*: explicitly specify the credentials of such a user via the `-Credential` parameter.
  - If neither is an option for you, you're out of luck; you'll need to ask an administrator to make the call for you ad hoc.
- That said, **even if your remote command *does* run with elevation, there's a common problem when that command tries to access *network resources (shares)***:

  - This is the infamous *double-hop problem*, discussed in the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/ps-remoting-second-hop), along with solution options.

Comment: My User is a Domain Administrator

Comment: @cosmo_, then it must be the double-hop problem.